# Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 220 but got an empty response - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel 8.

I want to send email but I got this error:

> Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 220 but got an empty
> response in file
> /var/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php
> on line 447

my config:

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

my code:

```
$this->dispatchNow(new SendEmailJob("*****@gmail.com"));
```

Comment: try clearing config cache. php artisan config:clear

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes, I got the same message.

Comment: do you have some firewall installed or blocking connections?

Comment: also if your password has special character then add quote MAIL_PASSWORD='************'  and if you are using gmail then enable two step verification  or try changing port 587

Comment: I changed to 587 port, but I got the same error.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian.try Prospero mentioned sollution. or changing MAIL_MAILER=smtp